# BehaviorSubject per group with GroupBy and Switch()

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have code which would need to have `GroupBy` and would need a unique `BehaviorSubject` per group of `Switch()`.

We have a stream of stock market values that we group by `Symbol` and perform level crossing across a number of levels (defined by a `BehaviorSubject` and a switch to always use the latest values).

So I need to go from this:

```
var feed = new Subject<double>();
var levels = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(new[] { 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0 });

levels
    .Select(thresholds => feed
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
        .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
        .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
        .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
```

And adapt the above to take a stream of `Tick` below and group by `Symbol`, each with its own level threshold detection on each grouped `Value`.

```
class Tick
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; } // The name.
    public decimal Value { get; set; } // The value.
}
```

Outline:

1. Take Market data
2. Group by Symbol
3. Alert on levels (depending on group name, using a dictionary of `BehaviorSubject`)
4. Output
5. Use `Switch()` to always use latest values from the dictionary

With a naive implementation I have a wrapper class (`ReactiveSymbolFeed` below), however blurring non-reactive and reactive code can introduce potential concurrency issues that reactive extensions otherwise deals neatly with.

**Questions please:**

Am I introducing any side effects, or will this cause issue at scale (say 100,000 messages per second across 2,000 groups)?

Since we have many groups each with their own BehaviorSubject that needs Switch() - can we rewrite our Reactive Extensions statement block to include the thresholds levels per symbol group, or is the above wrapper class the right way to do this?

**Further context and the wrapper class solution**

Instead I create a `ReactiveSymbolFeed` wrapper that will form the value part of a dictionary per symbol key.

```
class ReactiveSymbolFeed
{
    readonly BehaviorSubject<double[]> levels;
    readonly Subject<double> feed;

    public ReactiveSymbolFeed(double[] levels)
    {
        this.feed = new Subject<double>();
        this.levels = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(levels);

        this.levels
            .Select(thresholds => this.feed
            .Buffer(2, 1)
            .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
            .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
            .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(level => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current))))
         .Switch()
         .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Threshold)
         .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
    }

    public void OnNext(double value) => this.feed.OnNext(value);

    public void UpdateThresholds(double[] levels) => this.levels.OnNext(levels);
}
```

And then use with the below:

```
// Setup the detection thresholds per Symbol - each Symbol has 1 set of thresholds
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ReactiveSymbolFeed>();            
dictionary.Add("AAPL", new ReactiveSymbolFeed(new[] { 120.0, 125.0, 130.0 }));
dictionary.Add("VXX", new ReactiveSymbolFeed(new[] { 10.5, 15, 18.5, 20 }));

// Create some test tick data.
var ticks = new[]
{
    new Tick { Symbol = "AAPL", Value = 119.0 },
    new Tick { Symbol = "VXX", Value = 10.3 },
    new Tick { Symbol = "VXX", Value = 10.8 },
    new Tick { Symbol = "AAPL", Value = 121.0 },
    new Tick { Symbol = "AAPL", Value = 121.0 }
    // Followed by many other differnet Symbols and Values
};

// Loop through test data and dispatch it.
foreach(var tick in ticks)
{
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(tick.Symbol, out var value))
        value.OnNext(tick.Value);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include some kind of marble diagram or other kind of diagram which shows the input stream with the example input, maybe even with timing information, and the output/result you want from that specific input stream. It is difficult to follow with the provided source code what you are trying to do, what kind of stream or streams you want to build and how/where you want to consume them. If possible provide a MCVE, with emphasis on "minimal".